# Change certain index value of string in a list

Tags: python, string, list, indexing

`['0011111', '0011101', '0011110', '0011110', '0011100', '0010111', '0011000', '0011011', '0011000', '0010001', '0010100', '0010111', '0010110', '0010010', '0001110', '0001110', '0001010', '0001111', '0000111', '0001001', '0000101', '0001000', '0000100', '1000001']`

Hi newbie here, how can I change the first index string value "1" in the List, example "1000001" to "0000001". Thanks for solution

Comment: In which language ? You to change all first character of every entry in the array ?

Comment: Hi, python Language. No, only need to change if the first index of the string is '1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, if first character of the string in the list is `1`, change it to `0`:

```py
lst = [
    "0001000",
    "0000100",
    "1000001",
]

lst = [f"0{s[1:]}" if s.startswith("1") else s for s in lst]
print(lst)
```

Prints:

```
["0001000", "0000100", "0000001"]
```

---

EDIT: Using `str.replace`:

```py
lst = [s.replace("1", "0", 1) if s.startswith("1") else s for s in lst]
print(lst)
```

---

EDIT 2: If you want to change first `1` to `0` (regardless if `1` is found on first place or not you can do):

```py
lst = [
    "0001000",
    "0000100",
    "1000001",
]

lst = [s.replace("1", "0", 1) for s in lst]
print(lst)
```

Prints:

```py
['0000000', '0000000', '0000001']
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, may I ask is it able to use string.replace() method

Comment: @kidox Yes, when you're sure the string starts with `1` you can do e.g. `'10001'.replace('1', '0', 1)`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @kidox I've added version if you want to change first `1` to `0` (regardless of where the `1` is)

Answer (score 0):

Considering that all those strings are binary representations *07bit* (maximum value: ***127*** (***0x7F***, ***0b01111111***)), you could do (for each element):

- Convert it to an **base 2** (unsigned) integer
- Bit operation - clearing the *MSB* is equivalent to *and*ing with ***63*** (***0x3F***, ***0b00111111***)
- Convert the resulting integer back to (**base 2**) string

> ```py
> >>> # Original list
> >>> l7b = ["0011111", "0011101", "0011110", "0011110", "0011100", "0010111", "0011000", "0011011", "0011000", "0010001", "0010100", "0010111", "0010110", "0010010", "0001110", "0001110", "0001010", "0001111", "0000111", "0001001", "0000101", "0001000", "0000100", "1000001"]
> >>> l7b_msb_cleared = [f"{int(e, 2) & 0x3F:07b}" for e in l7b]
> >>> l7b_msb_cleared
> ['0011111', '0011101', '0011110', '0011110', '0011100', '0010111', '0011000', '0011011', '0011000', '0010001', '0010100', '0010111', '0010110', '0010010', '0001110', '0001110', '0001010', '0001111', '0000111', '0001001', '0000101', '0001000', '0000100', '0000001']
> >>>
> >>> [e == l7b[i] for i, e in enumerate(l7b_msb_cleared)]
> [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False]
> ```